# Extract specific keys from json using rxjs or native javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rxjs6

Assume that you have a json object as response. e.g

```
var items = [{
    title: 'sample 1',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/700/600/',
    description: 'lorem ipsum'
}, {
    title: 'sample 2',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/900/1200/',
    description: 'lorem ipsum'
}]
```

How to map the object in order to have only a result object like this:

```
[{
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/700/600/',

}, {
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/900/1200/',
}]
```

is there a clean way using rxjs operators? or simply js native?

I tried it using :

```
const source = from(items);
const result = source.pipe(
                    pluck('image')
                );
result.subscribe(val => console.log('new values ', val));
```

But it's not working. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: If you use `from`, it will emit each item in your original array separately, not as one array. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vanilla JS just [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the items and return objects with just that property:

```js
var items = [{
    title: 'sample 1',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/700/600/',
    description: 'lorem ipsum'
},{
    title: 'sample 2',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/900/1200/',
    description: 'lorem ipsum'
}];

const out = items.map(({image}) => ({ image }));

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Rxjs 6+**
It's works in rxjs like in Vanilla js. here is an example from [www.learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html):

```
// RxJS v6+
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit ({name: 'Joe', age: 30}, {name: 'Frank', age: 20},{name: 'Ryan', age: 50})
const source = from([
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Ryan', age: 50 }
]);
//grab each persons name, could also use pluck for this scenario
const example = source.pipe(map(({ name }) => name));
//output: "Joe","Frank","Ryan"
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```